# iPad overlay issues

Tags: css

the site I am working on has a number of different overlays which are controlled by CSS as follow (with different properties for each but same way):

```
 .box_4, .box_5, .box_6 {
   position: fixed;
   top: -1900px;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 101;
   width: 883px;
   margin-left: -400px;
```

}

These properties get applied when I close the overlay.

However on the iPad something strange happens, when I scroll the site just to check it out some of the overlays appear and disappear as soon as I touch the screen again.

Could that be due to the css?

Comment: can u show live link or jsfiddle or problum screenshoot or result screenshoot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many issues with mobile devices and `position:fixed;`

Instead of positioning them outside the viewport, you better hide/show the boxes.

Some references:

- http://www.8164.org/designing-for-the-ipad/
- http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/
- http://blog.mspace.fm/2009/10/01/iphone-mobile-safari-css-position-fixed/